# Angular 4 - How to redirect to parent route when launching a child route url directly?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-route-guards

The requirement is very simple. When a Child Route/Component's URL is entered directly in the browser, I should be able to redirect it to the parent route.

Questions :

1. How to identify a page refresh or if a child route is being launched directly?

2. If a child route is launched directly, how do I get its parent route url from the ActivatedRoute object ?

Solution Tried:

 I have this following piece of code in my Child Component's OnInit :

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

When navigating from a parent route the router events are being logged. But when launching the child URL directly, no events are logged.

Also tried *canActivateChild* in the route config, but no idea how to determine if a the parent component is loaded ?

 Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can add redirect rules or middleware to the server, it would be simplest, eg. redirect `/straight_to_children_no_go/**` to `/straight_to_children_no_go`. Add that before the usual ** -> index.html -rule.

If not, there's many (hacky) ways in angular, if someone can think of a cleaner way I'd like to know too. Eg. it could be a directive on links that when clicked, marks a flag in a service, which says this route is ok to go to, and build a canActivate guard based on that.